# Need to slice cards after page rendering react class component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a page where i need to show 9 cards initially and on click of show more i need to show more cards until API call has data. I used slice method and I am able to achieve same thing but because of slice SEO performance is impacted, these divs r not crawled by google, so now the problem is I need to render all div cards intially on the page and need to show only 9 by some other method. I have no clue how to achieve this. Can anyone please help me with this using class component in react.

```
import React from 'react';
import WebinarList from './WebinarList';
import Webinars from './Webinars';

export default class WebinarData extends React.Component{
constructor(...props) {
    super(...props);
    this.state = {
       isVisible: 9,
       setFlag: true,
       totalValue:0
    };
    this.showmoreWebinar = this.showmoreWebinar.bind(this);
    this.mathCal = this.mathCal.bind(this);
    
}

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const webinarList = this.props.webinarListInfo ? 
    this.props.webinarListInfo: null;
    const total =  webinarList? webinarList.length : 0;

    if(this.state.isVisible >= total){
        this.setState((old)=>{
            return {
                isVisible: 9,
            }
        })
    }
    
  }

  showmoreWebinar(offset, total){       
    this.setState((old)=>{
        return {
            isVisible: old.isVisible + offset,
        }
    })     
   }

   mathCal(n){
    if(n > 0)
        return Math.ceil(n/3.0) * 3;
    else if( n < 0)
        return Math.floor(n/3.0) * 3;
    else
        return 3;
   }

  render(){
  // console.log("in web");
  // console.log(this.props.webinarListInfo);
  const webinarList = this.props.webinarListInfo ? 
 this.props.webinarListInfo: null;
 const webinarBanner = this.props.webinarBanner && 
  this.props.webinarBanner.webinarLandingItems ? 
 this.props.webinarBanner.webinarLandingItems[0]: null;
 let offset = webinarBanner && webinarBanner.PageSize? 
 webinarBanner.PageSize : 9;
 offset= this.mathCal(offset);
const showMore = webinarBanner &&  webinarBanner.LoadMoreButtonText? 
 webinarBanner.LoadMoreButtonText: "Show more" ;
const list = webinarList ?  webinarList.map((item, index) => (
     <Webinars info={item} index={index} labelInfo= 
{this.props.webinarList}/>
    )
    ) : null;
const total =  webinarList? webinarList.length : 0;
return(
    <div>
        <div className="webinarData">
            <WebinarList labelInfo={this.props.webinarList} totalList= 
{webinarList}/>
            {list}           
        </div>
        <div className="l-show-more-btn">
        {webinarBanner ? (<button className="c-button showmore-webinar 
  is-desktop is-medium is-upper-case" 
                      style={{ display: this.state.isVisible >= total ? 
 'none' : 'block' }}
                onClick={() => this.showmoreWebinar(offset, total)} >
                {showMore}
            </button>) : null}
        </div>
     {total <= 0 ? (<div className=""><p  style={{textAlign:'center'}}> 
 {this.props.webinarList && this.props.webinarList.ResultNotFound? 
 this.props.webinarList.ResultNotFound: null}</p></div>):null}
    </div>
  );
  }
 }
```

Now i need to remove this slice method so everything is displayed on page load then need to slice it(basically show and hide kind of thing in UI).Following is the structure how it should look like in UI:

[image]

Comment: Since you're trying to "hide" elements from the DOM, you can use CSS to do so :) Can you provide a minimal code sample? Your current code sample is incomplete

Comment: Do u want me to post css file. since am doing anything from css for now. just using this slice method and showing the div.

Comment: Yes, even better if you could provide code that could reproduce the exact problem that you're describing in your post

Comment: Response is coming from API, can't share all code but this is the main code where i am generating list of cards. below is my component:

Comment: You can easily replace the real data with mock ones. When debugging, repro is a very important part of fixing it. So try to delete as many codes as you can and use mock data if the bug isn't coming from the real data this can speed up the debugging process and help you to pin down the real problem

Comment: Regarding the CSS solution, you can add a flag like: `showing: false` and use CSS to toggle the element with display property. But remember, these hidden elements are still rendered in the DOM

Comment: @konekoya thanks for the response but the problem is, it is not once for once. Every time user will click show more 6 new cards need to b displayedand since it is dynamic where will i use the flag

Comment: Also I have updated the code of of that particular component in the description box. Code is working fine i just need to remove slice from list and need to keep it from where it can be rendered for 1 time as 9 cards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233407/discussion-between-priya-and-konekoya).

Comment: I am still not able to get the thing